# PIC12F675 - 2 input 2 output 'XOR' output

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I am facing a peculiar problem or this is known to others which you can help educate me.

I'm running the below code on a PIC12F675, but the conditions never seem to work. Tried it on hardware, and also simulated the same in proteus, same result.

The problem - only one of the input toggles the output and not the other. 
Example - In my code GP1 and GP2 are inputs. When GP1 toggles, GP2 doesnt. If i reverse the bits or connections, when GP2 toggles, GP1 doesnt.

I just have 4 lines of code with if and else if, but not sure where am i going wrong. Spent more than 12 hours to figure out and finally posting it here. Any suggestions / advise please?

```
// PIC12F675 Configuration Bit Settings

// 'C' source line config statements

// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on GP4/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on GP5/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-Up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // GP3/MCLR pin function select (GP3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF       // Brown-out Detect Enable bit (BOD enabled)
#pragma config CP = ON          // Code Protection bit (Program Memory code protection is enabled)
#pragma config CPD = ON         // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is enabled)

// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

#include <xc.h>

void main(void) 
{
    ANSEL = 0x00; //disable analog inputs

    TRISIO1 = 1; //GP1 is input
    TRISIO2 = 1; //GP2 is input
    TRISIO4 = 0; //GP4 is output
    TRISIO5 = 0; //GP5 is output

    OPTION_REGbits.nGPPU = 0; //enable internal weak pull up resistors
    WPU1 = 1; //pull up enabled on GP1 INPUT
    WPU2 = 1; //pull up enabled on GP2 INPUT

    while(1)
    {
        if(GP1 == 0 && GP2 == 0) { GP4 = 1; GP5 = 1; } //if both the inputs are low, keep both the outputs high
        else if(GP1 == 0 && GP2 == 1) { GP4 = 1; GP5 = 0; } //if GP1 is low, keep GP5 low and GP4 high
        else if(GP1 == 1 && GP2 == 0) { GP4 = 0; GP5 = 1; } //if GP2 is low, keep GP4 low and GP5 high
        else if(GP1 == 1 && GP2 == 1) { GP4 = 1; GP5 = 1; } //if both the inputs are high, keep both the outputs high
        __delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: here is a simpler logic pseudocode `if GP1 == GP2 then GP4 = 1  else GP4 = GP2` .... add the GP5 assignment as needed

Comment: Tried all options, no luck. Finally changed the microcontroller to PIC16F886 and the same code works absolutely fine.

Comment: The comment from @Mike is wrong. The PIC12F675 has the old comparator module so set CMCON = 0x07; to disable it. But he is correct that it must be disabled to read the GP0 and GP1 inputs.

Comment: @Dan1138 thanks, I will fix the comment.

Comment: You had to switch off the comparator module. Add `CMCON = 0x07;`

Answer (score 1):

At Power On the `CMCON` register ist set to `0x00`, this means the pins `GP0` and `GP1` are set to analog.
If you want to use them as digital pins you had to set the `CMCON` register to `0x07h`.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the comparator did the trick. Though i thought about it yesterday, forgot to implement it. It is working as expected after setting the CMCON = 0x07;

Thanks to Mike and Dan1138 for your support and advise.